# IE7 - Background-color is too wide

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I have some text on top of an image.

In new browsers it's working fine.

But when I check in IE7, it looks like this: 
[image]

Somehow, IE7 is very keen, on giving the background color a width of a 100%. 
And I don't wanne fix it, by setting a width, since the length of the text will vary from page to page.

My CSS looks like this:

```
#sub-slideshow-wrapper h2 {
font-family: 'Droid Sans',sans-serif;
display: table;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: 900;
color: #000;
background: #e68e47; 
background: rgba(230,142,71,0.8);
padding: 7px;
margin: 0 0 3px 0;
}
```

And I know that IE7 is outdated, and that only 1.xxx is usnig it. But my is expection it to work on all browsers, even old ones.

Comment: `display:table` is not supported by IE7 - http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **must** support IE7 add zoom:1 and *display:inline (star hack to target IE6 & 7) to make IE 7 display them as if they were inline-block. **However this may have other effects you do not want.**

```
#sub-slideshow-wrapper h2 {
font-family: 'Droid Sans',sans-serif;

zoom: 1; /* added */
*display: inline; /* added */

display: table;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: 900;
color: #000;
background: #e68e47; 
background: rgba(230,142,71,0.8);
padding: 7px;
margin: 0 0 3px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table), IE7 does not support `display:table` so your `h2` is rendered with `display:block` (the standard `display` for `h2`), causing your problem.

As the global usage of IE7 is about 0.1%, I suggest you just leave it as it is.

Comment: I didn't. I have upvotet. But I'm the only one now, before there were another.

Comment: thanks :) I simply don't like it if someone downvotes my answer without commenting why ;)